# Getting a type mismatch parsing web request response to xml object in vba

Tags: xml, vba, sharepoint, webrequest, type-mismatch

I am getting a type mismatch (run timer error 13) for when parsing a web request response to an xml object in VBA.

The error is on this line:
`xmldoc.LoadXML WebRequest.responseXML`

```
    WebRequest.Open "POST", urlRef, False
    WebRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
    WebRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetURLSegments"
    strRequest = _
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> " & _
        "soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'> " & _
        "  <soap12:Body> " & _
        "   <GetURLSegments xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> " & _
        "    <strURL>" & strDocUrl & "</strURL>" & _
        "   </GetURLSegments>" & _
        "  </soap12:Body> " & _
        "</soap12:Envelope>"
        
    WebRequest.send strRequest 
    
    Dim xmldoc As Object
    Set xmldoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xmldoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmldoc.LoadXML WebRequest.responseXML
    For Each xmlnode In xmldoc.SelectNodes("//*[contains(name(),'strItemID')]")
        Debug.Print xmlnode.Text
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [loadXML Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754585(v=vs.85)) is expecting a String. You don't show us what the exact object behind `WebRequest` is but it looks like `WebRequest.responseXML` might [return an object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757066(v=vs.85)).

From that same document it is suggested you can get the body as a string by doing this:

`xmldoc.LoadXML WebRequest.responseXML.xml`

Comment: That is working, HackSlash, thank you very much.
How could I have determined that myself?

Comment: Those links I put in my answer are for the official MSDN documentation. When you search for those libraries and methods you always want to check the Microsoft pages. They aren't always super helpful but in your case you only need to know the type accepted by one method and the type returned of another. Sometimes it takes some guessing and checking.